# Angular 4 :load more data when the scroll move to the bottom with ngx-infinite-scroll and it not work

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll

### **Goal:**

I want to achieve a function that load more data when the scroll move to the bottom.
We used the **ngx-infinite-scroll** plug-in (https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll)  to implement it ,but it not working.

### **Expected results：**

it will triggle `onScrollDown()` function to load more data when the scroll move to the end.

### **Actual results:**

it triggled the `onScrollDown()` function when the scroll move to the middle approximately

### **Code:**

```
<div class="row" infinite-scroll [infiniteScrollDistance]='0'(scrolled)="onScrollDown()">
              ...show-list code...
</div>
```

`onScrollDown()` is ok, and i set infiniteScrollDistance to 0 but it not work.

So ,how can i fix it ?thanks in advance.

Comment: We have this in use, looks like: `<div data-infinite-scroll (scrolled)="loadGridDataScroll()" infiniteScrollDistance="0.3" infiniteScrollThrottle="500">`

Comment: yes, I have check the document ,`nfiniteScrollDistance="0"` mean that trigger scrolled function when the scroll move to the bottom ,but it not work.

Comment: Is it possible your div's bottom border is outside the scrollable area?

Comment: How did you make it work ? i am facing the same issue with ngx-infinite-scroll

Comment: Any fixes for this issues

Answer (score 1):

Try using **outer** container with parameters

```
[fromRoot]="true"
[infiniteScrollDistance]="0.1"
```